# PHP Search JSON File and get result

Tags: php, json

Here is my JSON File that contains my items. I would like to search for the item name and return the id.

CODE:

```
 $jsonitem = file_get_contents("data.json");

 $objitems = json_decode($jsonitem);


 $findById = function($id) use ($objname) {
  foreach (json_decode($objname) as $friend) {
    if ($friend->id === $id) return $friend->name;
  }
  return;
};

echo $findById('6') ?: 'No record found.';
```

JSON FILE:

```
[
       {
          "id":1,
          "name":"Candy Wrapper",
          "value":500,
       },
       {
          "id":2,
          "name":"Torch",
          "value":2000,
       }
    ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic is correct, but you have a couple of errors in your code:

- You are referencing `$objname`, which is not set
- You are decoding the data twice
- As [@Mikey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1022914/mikey) pointed out, your JSON is invalid because of trailing commas on the `"values"` lines.

Try:

```
$findById = function($id) use ($objitems) {
    foreach ($objitems as $friend) {
        if ($friend->id == $id) return $friend->name;
     }

    return false;
};
```

Comment: His JSON file is also invalid because of the trailing commas on the `"value"` lines.

Comment: @Mikey Good catch, I didn't notice that.

Comment: As for the trailing commas sorry for the confusion, I shortened my list as they are quite expansive with game variables and such. Thanks, this solved my problem!